# searching for max value of array with binary search (c)

Tags: c, binary-search

Write a function that receives an array of non-negative numbers `a`, with the size of `n`.

The array is sorted from low to high numbers and all those numbers are counted as `t`. the rest of the array `(n-t)` includes zeros.

For example:

For the array `{1,5,5,7,8,0,0,0}`  `(t=5)` and the function returns `8`.

For the array `{2,4,5,6,6,8,9,9}` `t=8` and the function returns `9`

For the array `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` `t=0` and so on..

The task is easy with runtime of `O(log(n))`:

```
int max_seq(int *a, int n)
{
    int low = 0, high = n - 1, mid;
    if (a[0] == 0) return 0; //a[n] = {0};
    while (high > low)
    {
        mid = (high + low) / 2;
        if (a[mid] == 0) // value is zero
            high = mid - 1;
        else //value is positive number
            if (a[mid + 1] == 0) //next number is zero
                return a[mid];
            else // next number is positive number
                low = mid + 1;
    }
    if (high == low)
        return a[low];
}
```

But the question is, how can I run the program with the runtime of **(log(t))**?
(while t is unknown)

Comment: What is the runtime if you set high to be t-1?

Comment: @FormerNcp Problem is, t is unknown.

Comment: Sorry, my bad..

Comment: Is this an academic problem? If so, perhaps the algorithm is already ok as it is and the challenge relies on proving it actually runs in log(t) by some mathematical proof? I always sucked at those classes, but this was the kind of curve-ball our teacher used to throw at us since he knew we would focus on code and not on proof.

Comment: @SimonBerthiaume yes it is, its a bonus question in one of the exams I had. But the order says to write a new solution for the program... so no proofs are required.

Comment: BTW. if    `if (high != low)` what does the function `int max_seq(int *a, int n)` return?

Comment: @sg7 depends on the input.. but probably, if you were outside the while-loop and the first condition (the {0} condition) then the input has to be sort of climbing up sequence without zeros.. so there is only 1 number at the end. the only way to get outside the while loop is when high==low..

Answer (score 0):

Before doing the divide and conquer, you could search more optimal initial values for `low` and `high` going from the beginning of the array and doubling the index in each iteration:

```
while(1) {
    if(high >= (n - 1)) {
        high = n - 1;
        break;
    }
    if(a[high] == 0)
        break;
    low = high;
    high *= 2;
}
```